# active admin action item not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

[I am following active_admin's documentation on action items](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#rendering) trying to add an "approve" action to my admin view.

I have my activeadmin register set up like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register PendingClaim do


  action_item :approve, method: :post, only: [:show, :index] do
    link_to('Approve', "#")
  end


  index do
    column "Business ID", :business_id
    column "User ID", :user_id
    column "Claim approved by Admin?", :approved
    column :created_at
  end



  controller do
    # This code is evaluated within the controller class

    def approve
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

but it doesn't show the approve action in the table. I want the approve action to map to the #approve action in the PendingClaim controller. Not sure what I have to do here...

I also tried adding actions to my index like so:

```
  index do
    column "Business ID", :business_id
    column "User ID", :user_id
    column "Claim approved by Admin?", :approved
    column :created_at
    actions
  end
```

but that just showed the default actions without my custom approve action

EDIT --

Based on @Omnigazer's answer, I changed my code to

```
ActiveAdmin.register PendingClaim do


  member_action :approve, only: :index do
    redirect_to resource_path, notice: "Approved!"
  end


  index do
    column "Business ID", :business_id
    column "User ID", :user_id
    column "Claim approved by Admin?", :approved
    column :created_at
  end



  controller do
    # This code is evaluated within the controller class

    def approve
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

but that still doesn't show the action.

EDIT --

Thanks to Omnigazer, I have managed to get it working, my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register PendingClaim do
  member_action :approve, method: :post, only: :index do
  end

  index do
    column :created_at
    column 'Business ID', :business_id
    column 'User ID', :user_id
    column 'Claim approved by Admin?', :approved
    actions defaults: false do |pending_claim|
      params = { business_id: pending_claim.business_id,
                 user_id: pending_claim.user_id }
      link_to('Approve', approve_admin_pending_claim_path(pending_claim, params), method: :post)
    end
  end

  controller do
    # This code is evaluated within the controller class

    def approve
      business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
      user = Business.find(params[:user_id])
      business.user_id = user.id
      business.verified = true
      if business.save
        resource.approved = true
        resource.save
        redirect_to resource_path(resource), notice: 'Claim Approved!'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. You wrote it all with proper explanation. I could not find such a well-explained way anywhere. Exactly same issue I had and your question+answer solved it :) THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actions items appear in the upper right corner of the page, where the "create %{model_name%}" button usually resides. Try looking for it there. Otherwise, your code looks valid. Although ActiveAdmin has its own DSL methods "collection_action" and "member_action" for cases like yours. Try looking them up in the docs.

EDIT:
If you want to append an action item next to the default actions, try this:

```
index do
  ...
  actions defaults: true do |order|
    link_to('Approve', "#")
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah ok, I noticed the button, but what I really wanted was the link next to the resource, which is the member_action if I'm reading the docs correctly... I updated my code with member_action, but it doesn't seem to show anything though... any pointers? The active admin documentation is not so clear to me

Comment: Thanks! that helped me get my solution! Another question if you don't mind - what is the purpose of the member_action at the top of the file? is it solely to generate the route?

Answer (score 0):

```
#action_item(name = nil, options = {}, &block) ⇒ Object
```

> Add a new action item to the resource
>
> Parameters: name (Symbol) (defaults to: nil) options (Hash) (defaults
>   to: {}) — valid keys include: :only: A single or array of controller
>   actions to display this action item on. :except: A single or array of
>   controller actions not to
>
> display this action item on.

[action_item documentaion](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/DSL#action_item-instance_method)

I think there is no option `method:` option there

active admin documentation has good example how to use it

```
page_action :add_event, method: :post do
  # ...
  redirect_to admin_calendar_path, notice: "Your event was added"
end

action_item :add do
  link_to "Add Event", admin_calendar_add_event_path, method: :post
end
```

[source](http://activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html#add-a-page-action)